# Как заменить сразу несколько символов в preg_match на другие разные символы

Tags: php

https://ideone.com/j7wdru

```
[<?php
$text = "Привет,ты дурак?Если:нет то координально тебя поздравляю пишы?";
$remarks = preg_replace('/[,]/iu', ', ', $text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[;]/iu', '; ', $text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[!]/iu', '! ', $text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[?]/iu', '? ', $text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[:]/iu', ': ', $text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[жЖ][ыЫ]/iu','жи',$text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[шШ][ыЫ]/iu','ши',$text);
$remarks = preg_replace('/[к][о][о][р][д][и][н][а][л][ь][н][о]/iu','кардинально',$text);
echo $remarks;]
```

Почему не работают функции preg_match и как можно их укомпплектовать в одну.

Comment: Заранее извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, гугл не помог :(

Comment: `([,;:! ....])` => `$1 `

Comment: Благодарю :) вас

Comment: Если после условной запятой уже есть пробел - вы не будете убирать лишний, добавленный вашей регуляркой?